Does font apps font.xml have fallback options?

<sans>

    <!-- Regular SamsungSans Fonts -->

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-Regular.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-Bold.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans-Bold.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-Black.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans-Black.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-Extrabold.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans-Extrabold.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-Light.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans-Light.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-Medium.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans-Medium.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-Semibold.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans-Semibold.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-Thin.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans-Thin.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

    <file>

        <filename>Samsungsans-UltraLight.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>DroidSans-UltraLight.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

  

</sans>

I was modding the Samsungsans app, which is available to change fonts in the settings. So, I was wondering if there are any fallback options in this xml file. Also, I'd like to change system font (both fonts and emojis) completely. Is there a specific tag for the emojis? (I don't think there is, but I'm don't know for sure)
I tried renaming droid name
    <file>

        <filename>fallback_or_emoji.ttf</filename>

        <droidname>NotoColorEmoji.ttf</droidname>

    </file>

